# Stückelberg mechanism and the axion

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, field-theory, gauge-theory, axion

In the so-called Stückelberg mechanism we have the BF term

$$
\sim \int m\; B_2\wedge F ~,
$$

where the field $B_2$ is a 2-form and $F$ is the field strength arising from a $U(1)$.

The Stückelberg mechanism allows to introduce a scalar field $\eta$ (Axion) to rewrite the BF term in a local equivalent form according to

$$
\int_{4d} m\; B_2 \wedge F \rightarrow -\frac{1}{2}\int_{4d}(m\;A+d\eta)^2 \;
$$
with $F=dA$.

Now, the 2-form $B_2$ is related (Hodge duals) to a $0$-form $\Phi$ in four dimensions.

$$
B_2 \sim -\Phi~.
$$

Thus, it seems that we can get the following

$$
\int_{4d} m\; B_2 \wedge F \rightarrow -\frac{1}{2}\int_{4d}(m\;A+d\Phi)^2.
$$

**Question**:

1. Why can we assume that the $\Phi$ corresponds to the axion $\eta$?
2. What happens to the *minus*? Shouldn't we get:

$$
\int_{4d} m\; B_2 \wedge F \rightarrow -\frac{1}{2}\int_{4d}(m\;A-d\Phi)^2.
$$

The Stückelberg mechanism can be found e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0307252) on page 63.

Comment: Can you please explain why you introduce $\Phi$? When dualising the Lagrangian (from $B_2$ to its dual) you need to add a Lagrange multiplier term $\int \eta dH_3$ to ensure $dH_3=0$. The equations of motion of $H_3$ should read something like $\star H_3 \sim mA + d\eta$ (I didn't verify the signs). You can subsitute $H_3$ to get the term $|mA + d\eta|^2$.

Comment: It's coming from the generalised Green-Schwarz mechanism. Basically, you have a $5$-form and a $3$-form, which by dimensional reduction become the $2$-form and the $0$-form. And $\Phi$ is related by duality to $B_2$. In some sense my $\Phi$ should be the Lagrangian multiplier $\eta$. What do you mean, when you say the dual to $B_2$?

Comment: Yes, I think your $\Phi$ should be the Lagrange multiplier $\eta$. This is how I think of the dual of $B_2$. The field strength is $H_3 = dB_2$, hence the Hodge dual field strength is $F_1 = \star H_3$. Hence, the dual to $B_2$ is a $0$-form $C_0$ with $F_1 = dC_0$. What you should find is that $dC_0 \sim mA + d\eta$. Hence, $C_0$ is not exactly $\eta$.

Comment: I put more details with hopefully correct signs in the post below.

Comment: Is there a way to deduce $C_0$ if $dC_0 \sim mA+d\eta$? What would it be in that case?

Comment: One needs to integrate, but since $A$ is generally not exact, there is no "nice" general expression. I think, one needs specific field configurations to find $C_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in addition to the comments above, I now checked the signs. Here is the maths. We start with the Lagrangian
$$ \mathscr{L} = - \frac{1}{2}H_3 \wedge \star H_3 + m B_2 \wedge F \ ,$$
where I omitted the kinetic term $F \wedge \star F$, because it is not relevant for the dualisation.

Now I want to find the Lagrangian for the dual of $B_2$. For this, we need to add a Lagrange multiplier term:

$$ \mathscr{L} = - \frac{1}{2}H_3 \wedge \star H_3 + m B_2 \wedge F - \eta dH_3 \ .$$

Why minus and not plus? Because I want to get $|mA+d\eta|^2$ and not $|mA-d\eta|^2$. ;-) Here I use the notation $|F|^2 = F \wedge \star F$.

This extra term ensures that we have the Bianchi identity $dH_3=0$ (when integrating out $\eta$).

Since $F=dA$, we can now rewrite

$$ \mathscr{L} = - \frac{1}{2}H_3 \wedge \star H_3 - m H_3 \wedge A - H_3 \wedge d\eta \ ,$$

where I dropped all boundary terms $d(...)$.

When we vary with respect to $H_3$, we obtain:
$$ 0 = \delta H_3 \wedge \left[- \star H_3  - (mA + d\eta) \right] \ , $$
i.e. we get the equation of motion
$$ \star H_3 = - (mA + d\eta)$$
Since $H_3$ is a $3$-form in 4D with Lorentzian signature, we have $\star(\star H_3)=H_3$.

We can now go back to our Lagrangian (with the Lagrange multiplier) and substitute $\star H_3$ and $H_3$. I obtain
$$ \mathscr{L} = - \frac{1}{2}|mA + d\eta|^2 \ ,$$
as desired.

Comment: If I want $ \mathscr{L} = - \frac{1}{2}(mA - d\eta^2 )$ (because I want different signs in the transformation behaviour of the gauge field and the axion) I have to change de sign of the axion? E.g. my $B_2$ is dual to $-\eta$. Right?

Comment: Yes, field redefinitions like $\eta \to - \eta$ are no problem. But are you sure you want a minus sign if you want different signs in transformation? (I guess you mean gauge transformations? But maybe I just don't get what you mean.)

Comment: I want $A\rightarrow A -d\Lambda$ and $\eta\rightarrow \eta + \Lambda$. Or is there some problem I don't see?

Comment: But then $A-d\eta \to A - d\Lambda - d\eta - d\Lambda = A-d\eta - 2d\Lambda$. With plus sign, however, it would work. Right?

Comment: Yes! That was a typo. Thank you!